# What's the best practice to collect data from different clients?

Tags: mongodb, client-server, database

Here are the details of my use case:

1. What's my data..
   There would be user experiences, error report, state info and so on. The data is fragmented and may change in the future. So I plan to use NoSQL, maybe mongodb, to save data in the server.
2. What are the clients..
   They are clients written in different languages, like C#, C++, LabVIEW and so on. Some don't even have an access to a mongodb driver, so of course it's not an option to communicate with database directly. And framework like below is needed.

Clients -> (Some protocol) -> Broker -> Database.

As those clients are not web client, so common web server using http may not suit for my case, right? Is there any suggestion for the protocol, broker and database, Or even a new framework.
My goal is to make the clients can send data as convenient as possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, web server with http protocal could suit for the use case, I think.

Mostly I want is a universal API for different kinds of clients to save data to cloud. Http has method GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, so with a RESTful API it is naturlly suitable for operate data, I think.

My solution at last is Node.js(Express) + Mongodb (a quite common group), and a RESTful API is provided via Express web server, clients can use http to operate data conviencely. Also, it is quite light weight and easy to get started.

Here is some tutorial: http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/

Answer (score 1):

This is not really new, but a message driven application, which is a well understood pattern.

I did this mostly in Java, so I will stick to this language here.

A broker alone would be not enough here. Let us say you use [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org) as you message broker, you would still need to get your data into the database, since MQ is... ...a message queue. So you need a part which gets the messages out of MQ, processes them according to your business rules and stores them in the (correct) database instance, and the correct collection/bucket/table. Of course you could write this part by hand, but that would be pretty much reinventing the wheel. There is a notion of a "message routing and mediation engine", and the most commonly suggested here is [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org), which has [quite some components](http://camel.apache.org/components.html) to communicate with databases and other so called consumers and producers. And that is the key point. In general, if possible, your clients should send their data to the message broker directly. But, if they can't, they can simply send text files or make REST calls – there are actually too many options to list here. This incoming data can be preprocessed and normalized to your standard format by a *"route"* in Apache Camel (a set of a consumer, conversion rules and a producer, in it's simplest form) and send as an AMQP message to MQ. From there, another Camel route can process the AMQP messages, apply your business rules and store the data in the database... ...or whatever else may come to your mind (for example sending an email).

So this solution supports a multitude of protocols for incoming and outgoing messages (as long as they are supported by Camel) and you have your business rules in a centralized and well defined location.

To implement this, I'd strongly suggest using [Apache ServiceMix](http://servicemix.apache.org), which is a distribution of ActiveMQ, Camel and a system to manage the components and business rules.

Comment: Thank you. I am not quite familiar with this kind of pattern, but what you have mentioned seems an enterprise level solution. Camel -> MQ -> Camel(a lot of business rules) -> Database(or something else), it suports more functions than I need. I hope maybe there is some light weighted solution can be implemented quickly. Just using a protocol and a server broker to make it easy for clients to save data?

Comment: Not really. Because you still would need to have all clients speak the same protocol and even have to produce the same data.